# Miss libdc1394-dev in Diamondback

Tags: ros, rosdep, camera1394

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I built camera1394 package, I was told I missed libdc1394-dev as shown below.

---

```
$ rosdep install camera1394

Failed to find rosdep libdc1394-dev for package trunk on OS:ubuntu version:natty
rosdep install ERROR:
failed to install libdc1394-dev
```

My ROS works on Ubuntu 11.04. My current ROS version is Diamondback which should support Natty. And It seems like libdc1394-22-dev is the right library on Ubuntu, not libdc1394-dev.

How can I solve this problem? Thanks for help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40330/miss-libdc1394-dev-in-diamondback/) by [LeonInTexas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2961/leonintexas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2012-08-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Fuerte is not supported on Ubuntu Natty. How did you install it?

If you had the Fuerte version of `rosdep`, it should say:

```
$ rosdep resolve libdc1394-dev --os=ubuntu:natty
#apt
libdc1394-22-dev
```

Although Fuerte may have problems running Natty, I would expect `camera1394` itself to work OK.

Overall, I recommend either upgrading to Ubuntu Precise or Oneiric, or going back to ROS Electric.

EDIT: Now you mention Diamondback, which *is* supported on Natty (though not actively at this point).

Why can't you install `ros-diamondback-camera-drivers` using apt-get?

I don't know why the Diamondback `rosdep` is not working correctly for you. Nevertheless, you should be able to install that library by hand and compile the camera driver:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libdc1394-22-dev
$ rosmake camera1394 --no-rosdep
```

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-08-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1